# How can I add copyright information to my photos with a Sony Alpha 37?

Tags: metadata, sony, copyright

I have a SONY Alpha 37 Camera. I have been looking for the possibility to enter the author´s name and copyright details, but I found nothing.

Does anybody know how can I get it?

Comment: Do you want this added to the metadata, or written as a visible watermark?

Comment: To the EXIF metadata

Answer (score 3):

According to the [sybersitizen's](https://www.dpreview.com/members/1524468683) response to a [similar question at dpreview.com](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3349933#forum-post-50444826), you can't do it.

The question at dpreview was:

> Read the manual and can't find it. How do you enter your name/ copyright info on the A99 so it'll show up in the EXIF info?  Thx

The answer:

> You can't with the A99 or any other Alpha. Gotta do it with software later.

Comment: Could you mention any strong references, where can I validate your assumption

Comment: @AyoubFalah I don't follow. I assumed you wanted to write your copyright to the EXIF information (which you later verified in your comment/response to mattdm. I'm just repeating what I read at dpreview.com, which I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Seems like it would be difficult to provide strong references that something does not exist.  Is there anything in your manual?

Comment: @Ayoub Falah the only strong reference is the Sony customer support. Contact them.